# error response from daemon: pull access denied for image, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login':

Tags: docker, docker-image

i have logged in and am using m1 mac.
error message below:Error response from daemon: pull access denied for mysqlmbtamasterimg, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied

[image: 1]

would appreciate any insights

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be trying to build the image.

If so, try:

```bash
docker build --tag=mysqlmbtamasterimg --file=./Dockerfile .
```

Don't omit that final space then period at the end of the command.